# Downlink and Uplink thoughput calculation for LTE bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth, telecommunication, lte

Three LTE small cells located in a room approximately same distance between each other which are having some interference. All the cells are same having bandwidth (**15MHz**) and same frequency configured.

Each cell is connected with a three separate **UE**(Phone) and calculated **downlink** and **uplink** throughput,
Each phone is receiving ~ ( **25 to 38 Mbps**).

Later i changed the bandwidth of 1 cell to **10 MHz** and other two cells to **5 Mhz** and appropriate frequency and calculated **downlink** and **uplink** throughput,

Each phone is higher throughput compared to previous test.~( **29 to 46 Mbps**).

My question here is , as the bandwidth is reduced significantly i assume the through also should drop as well, but the  throughput is higher than before.

Answer (score 0):

> All the cells are same having bandwidth (15MHz) and same frequency configured.

That's the key moment, because they do interfere with each other. What is the reason of using the same frequency band for three cells?

> Each phone is higher throughput compared to previous test.~( 29 to 46 Mbps).
>   My question here is , as the bandwidth is reduced significantly i assume the through also should drop as well, but the throughput is higher than before.

Most likely, reducing the bandwidth reduced the level of total interference.